# Do well accepted questions lifts out answer ban?

Tags: discussion, answers, post-ban, banning

I am currently in an answer ban, yes it sucks, maybe because I'm a newbie, but the reason I got poorly received answers is that my answers were not voted up nor voted down. This happens because the asker on the post I had answered did not even rate it, I got four answers who suffer the same problem.

In the ban notice, I knew that it will be lifted if the answers will be voted up and now I must not delete them instead improve. My question is, do well-accepted questions ( I can still raise a question) lifts that ban or not?

Comment: Not that I want to fuel the fire, but the language you use here already shows that there may be more things wrong. Try writing questions and answers in plain English for starters and keep their formatting clean. "Because" is only a few keystrokes more than "bcoz". Did you take the tour yet? http://stackoverflow.com/tour . Or read through the help center? http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Thanks for the lesson sir @Gimby.

Comment: Other issues: lower case i. Multiple commas in a row where one would be enough. Not breaking the post into paragraphs. In general - if you don't put the effort into the question (making it as correct and as easy to read as possible), you won't get as good a reception.

Comment: Thanks, @Oded, now I learned that in this community grammar and proper punctuations do matter. Thanks for accommodating me here.I am now making use of my Grammarly plugin to help me write well.

Comment: Why do you say you are in an answer ban? I don't see evidence of that.

Comment: @Oded sir, I can say so for the reason that when I answer a question ( which happen I know and have the idea how to resolve) the stack overflow will say "we don't accept an answer from this account anymore" then it links me on how can I get out of the ban.

Comment: Oh.. you maybe IP banned?